# Use xdotool to send special characters

Tags: command-line, bash, python

I am trying to control the volume of omxplayer while the track is playing. I can use the keyboards <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>–</kbd> keys.  However I want to control the volume using a python script.
The following script works to pause and unpause omxplayer, by sending p using xdotool.

xdotool does not accept special characters. Is there a work around for this?

When I replace the <kbd>p</kbd> with <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>–</kbd>, I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid key sequence '-'
Failure converting key sequence '-' to keycodes
Error: Invalid key sequence '-'
Failure converting key sequence '-' to keycodes
xdo_send_keysequence_window reported an error for string '-'
```

Here is the script that I am using:

```py
threading.Thread(target=play_clip).start()
print"startng tone"
time.sleep(1)
while a==1:
    print 'ttt'
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('xdotool key p')
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('xdotool key p')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xdotool key minus plus
```

will simulate hitting <kbd>-</kbd>and <kbd>+</kbd>.